# Is the median a sufficient statistic for a uniform distribution on $(-θ, θ)$?

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, median, sufficient-statistics

I have a uniform distribution on $(-θ, θ)$ and I have to find a sufficient statistic. I know that the order statistic [$x_{(1)}$, $x_{(n)}$] are jointly minimal sufficient but I was wondering whether I can say that [$x_{(1)}$, $x_{(m)}$, $x_{(n)}$] is sufficient for $θ$. (where $x_{(m)}$ is the median such that if I have 10 observation $x_{(m)}$ would be $x_{(5)}$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sufficiency of the order statistic implies (in this case) that the mapping you have written out is also sufficient, by the Fisher-Neyman factorization lemma. Intuitively, a sufficient statistic compresses the data to only contain the parts that are 'relevant' for estimating $\theta$. Since you have added no new information on $\theta$, but also not removed the minimum and maximum the statistic will still be sufficient. You can show this pretty easily: Use that the order statistic is sufficient. Then you can factorize the density into two functions, one of $X$ and one of $(\theta, T(X))$ (where $T$ is the statistic). Construct $\tilde{T}$ by
  $$
  \tilde{T} = T(X) + 0\cdot X_{(m)} 
  $$
Then you can surely plug in $\tilde{T}$ instead of $T$, and then you will have still factorized the density. As such, the statistic is sufficient.

It is worth it, however, to note that the median statistic in itself is *not* sufficient for $\theta$, however.